# Leer archivo Excel desde Java Tomcat

Tags: java, excel, tomcat

Estoy realizando una aplicación web con *Java* y utilizando *Tomcat 8.5* para correrla en local. Mi aplicación tiene que leer un archivo *Excel* y guardar los datos en variables. Utilizo la librería *POI*, y cuando ejecuto el código sin pasar por el servidor desde el método `main` me lo lee perfectamente, pero cuando lo hago a través de un *servlet* me lanza una excepción.

Este es el código que si funciona:

```
package excel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class LeerXLSX {
    /*public LeerXLSX(){

}*/

public LeerXLSX(File fileName) throws ParseException{
    if (fileName.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Existe");
    }
    ArrayList cellDataList = new ArrayList();
    try{
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        XSSFSheet hssfSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIterator = hssfSheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()){
            XSSFRow hssfRow = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
            Iterator iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();
            ArrayList cellTempList = new ArrayList();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                XSSFCell hssfCell = (XSSFCell) iterator.next();
                cellTempList.add(hssfCell);
            }
            cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Leer(cellDataList);
}

private void Leer(ArrayList cellDataList) {
    int nFilas = cellDataList.size();
    ArrayList<String> fila[] = new ArrayList[nFilas];

    for (int i = 0; i < cellDataList.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList cellTempList = (ArrayList) cellDataList.get(i);
        fila[i]= new ArrayList();
        for (int j = 0; j < cellTempList.size(); j++) {
            XSSFCell hssfCell = (XSSFCell) cellTempList.get(j);
            String stringCellValue = hssfCell.toString();
            //System.out.print(stringCellValue + " ");
            fila[i].add(stringCellValue);
        }
        System.out.println("fila" + i +fila[i]);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        File f = new File("test.xlsx");
        if (f.exists()) {
            LeerXLSX pb = new LeerXLSX(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto a través de *Tomcat* simplemente quito el `main` y lo llamo desde el *servlet*.

```
package excel;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class LeerXLSX {
    /*public LeerXLSX(){

    }*/

    public LeerXLSX(File fileName) throws ParseException{
        if (fileName.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Existe");
        }
        ArrayList cellDataList = new ArrayList();
        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            XSSFSheet hssfSheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator rowIterator = hssfSheet.rowIterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()){
                XSSFRow hssfRow = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                Iterator iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();
                ArrayList cellTempList = new ArrayList();
                while (iterator.hasNext()){
                    XSSFCell hssfCell = (XSSFCell) iterator.next();
                    cellTempList.add(hssfCell);
                }
                cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Leer(cellDataList);
    }

    private void Leer(ArrayList cellDataList) {
        int nFilas = cellDataList.size();
        ArrayList<String> fila[] = new ArrayList[nFilas];

        for (int i = 0; i < cellDataList.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList cellTempList = (ArrayList) cellDataList.get(i);
            fila[i]= new ArrayList();
            for (int j = 0; j < cellTempList.size(); j++) {
                XSSFCell hssfCell = (XSSFCell) cellTempList.get(j);
                String stringCellValue = hssfCell.toString();
                //System.out.print(stringCellValue + " ");
                fila[i].add(stringCellValue);
            }
            System.out.println("fila" + i +fila[i]);
        }

    }

    /*public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        File f = new File("test.xlsx");
        if (f.exists()) {
            LeerXLSX pb = new LeerXLSX(f);
        }
    }*/
}
```

... y el *servlet*:

```
package controlador;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServletExcel
 */
@WebServlet("/ServletExcel")
public class ServletExcel extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ServletExcel() {
        super();

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        File f = new File("C:/Users/CrisH/workspace/Proyectos/test.xlsx");
        try {
            LeerXLSX l = new LeerXLSX(f);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

El error que me lanza es:

```
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [controlador.ServletExcel] en el contexto con ruta [/Proyectos] lanzó la excepción [La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una excepción] con causa raíz
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at excel.LeerXLSX.<init>(LeerXLSX.java:35)
    at controlador.ServletExcel.doGet(ServletExcel.java:43)
```

Debugeando en `XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);` me salta la clase `ApplicationFilterChain.class`:

> **Class File Editor**
>   Source not found
>   The source attachment does not contain the source for the file `ApplicationFilterChain.class`.
>   You can change the source attachment by clicking **Change Attached Source** below:

Anteriormente me saltaba la librería **cataliana.jar**, la descargué y la volví a meter en el proyecto.

Comment: Tienes agregada la librería a la carpeta `lib`, dentro de `WEB-INF` de tu proyecto? Dice que no te encuentra la clase `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook` si es asi y aun asi no te funciona, intenta agregando el `.jar` a las librerias del `tomcat`

Comment: Vale, estaba añadiendo la librería desde las propiedades de proyecto como external JARs. Ha sido añadirlas a la carpeta lib de WEB-INF y funciona. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: De nada, si me aceptas la respuesta, eternamente agradecido :)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que tener agregada la librería a la carpeta `lib`, dentro de `WEB-INF` de tu proyecto. Dice que no te encuentra la clase `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook` si es asi y aun asi no te funciona, intenta agregando el `.jar` a las librerias del `tomcat`